# File icon showing in properties but not in nautilus

Tags: unity, nautilus, icons

[image]

As you can see from the image the icon for python files displays fine in the properties window but not in nautilus. Even more, the Perl icon displays fine in nautilus (both icons are from the same Numix directory) I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, does anybody know what may be causing this?